# How to find a monthly aggregation using python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a weekly data aggregation but also need a monthly data aggregation using a loop 12 times for each month.

Is there anyone that can help me?

I have the weekly code as reference.

Comment: Hello friendorino, usually when making question I recommend that you give a sample data and try to display your wanted result

Comment: to get help it is always recommended to provide an [mre]